# Change the node attributes in Org-mode Mind-Map

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Trying to modify [org-mind-map](https://github.com/theodorewiles/org-mind-map) to change the attributes of the nodes and edges. I haven't really learned the internals of emacs and org-mode, and use them "as is" - without making modifications, and therefore not really understanding. So, it would be great if one could explain what custom options means and how to implement them in a org file. This will help me work with other org-mode files also. I do not know how to even call this problem properly, otherwise I would have google-fu'd this.

So, as an example, if I want to change the "shape" of node to "circle" for only a particular heading, where should that property be written within the headline of the org file? So in the example taken from the main project, this works.

```
* This is an org-mode tree with tags
:PROPERTIES:
:OMM-COLOR: GREEN
:OMM-LEGEND: Legend entry
:END:
```

To change the shape of the node, the documentation mentions using :OMM-NODE-FMT and something about custom options.

```
;;; Customizable Options:
;; Below is a list of customizable options:

;;  `org-mind-map-default-node-attribs'
;;    Alist of default node attributes and values.
;;    default = '(("shape" . "plaintext"))

;; You can customize the style of the graph by adding :OMM-NODE-FMT and :OMM-EDGE-FMT properties
;; to the headlines in the tree.
```

And in the code the documentation tells us,

```
(defcustom org-mind-map-default-node-attribs '(("shape" . "plaintext"))
  "Alist of default node attributes and values.
Each item in the alist should be a cons cell of the form (ATTRIB . VALUE)
where ATTRIB and VALUE are strings.
For a list of value attributes, see here: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html"
  :type '(alist :key-type (string :tag "Attribute") :value-type (string :tag " Value"))
  :group 'org-mind-map)
```

So, for a headline in org-mode if I want to change the shape of the node, where should I put those options? Should I do something like this

```
* This is an org-mode tree with tags
:PROPERTIES:
:OMM-NODE-FMT: '(("shape" . "circle"))
:OMM-COLOR: GREEN
:OMM-LEGEND: Legend entry
:END:
```

This isn't working, of course. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `:OMM-NODE-FMT:` and `:OMM-EDGE-FMT:` you actually have to create a
function and add it to `org-mind-map-node-formats` respectively `org-mind-map-node-formats`.

Fortunately there are some auxiliary macros predefined to make this as easy as
possible:

- for node: `(org-mind-map-make-node-fn NAME DOC PROPS &optional SHAPE COLOR OTHER)`
- for edge: `(org-mind-map-make-edge-fn NAME DOC PROPS &optional STYLE COLOR OTHER)`

Unfortunately the node one seems to not have been updated after some changes to
org-mind-map and is therefore only useable with a little workaround (see below).
I created a new [issue](https://github.com/theodorewiles/org-mind-map/issues/48#issue-527984456) on the github page. The owner of org-mind-map has not been
active on github for a long time, so this will probably not be resolved.

This is how you do it:

## :OMM-NODE-FMT:

```lisp
(require 'ox-org)
(org-mind-map-make-node-fn circle "circle shape" nil "circle" nil nil)
;; until fixed: wrap inside a lambda.
(add-to-list 'org-mind-map-node-formats
             '("circle" . (lambda (title tags color hm el &optional content images)
                            (org-mind-map-circle-node title tags color hm el))))
```

*Check the documentation for `org-mind-map-make-node-fn` to get more infos about the arguments.*

Then use as follows:

```
* circle
:PROPERTIES:
:OMM-NODE-FMT: circle
:END:

** rectangle
```

Result:

[image: mind map with circle and rectangle shape]

## :OMM-EDGE-FMT:

This would be the way to do it, but **it's not working** (created another issue on the github page):

```lisp
(require 'ox-org)
(org-mind-map-make-edge-fn dashed "dashed, red and empty arrowhead"
                           nil "dashed" "red" "arrowhead=empty")
(add-to-list 'org-mind-map-edge-formats
             '("dashed" . org-mind-map-dashed-edge))
```

Even changing `(setq org-mind-map-edge-format-default "[style=dotted]")` has no
effect.

Only way to change edge style globally is by modifying `(setq
org-mind-map-default-edge-attribs '(("style" . "dotted")))`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Hubisan. Your solution did solve some problems. While I am able to get circle shapes, and can also add different attributes, however this package feels kind of broken. I don't have knowledge of what goes under the hood of emacs, elisp and org-mode, so I am working with correlations here. I am moving to pure Graphviz, but will look forward to working with org-mode sometimes later. Much thanks for your sincere reply!

Comment: @solyarist [plantuml](http://plantuml.com/mindmap-diagram) also supports mind mapping and it can be used with [org-babel](http://eschulte.github.io/babel-dev/DONE-integrate-plantuml-support.html).

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. Plantuml looks promising for my problem.